# VBA code how select an option from drop down

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I have a problem with the VBA code. I want to select and change the Option value

```
<div class="pull-left">
        <span data-bind="text: allTasks.itemsFromIndex">1</span> To
        <span data-bind="text: allTasks.itemsToIndex">10</span> Of
        <span data-bind="text: allTasks.totalCount">39</span> All Pending Tasks
    </div>
        Show
        <select data-bind="value: allTasks.pageSize">
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        Per Page
```

Comment: Care to specify what problem you are having? You have neither supplied the full code nor the problem. This question contains no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it looks like you want to select a dropdown option by automating the IE browser using VBA.

We can see that the dropdown element does not have an ID or Name to access it. so here we can try to find that specific element using its `data-bind` attribute value.

VBA code:

```
Sub demo()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim selectElement As HTMLSelectElement
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://Your_Site_URL_here..."  'Modify the URL here...

    Do While ie.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
        
    Set selectElement = ie.document.querySelector("select[data-bind='value: allTasks.pageSize']")
    selectElement.Options(3).Selected = True  ' Note that index value starts from 0...
   
    'ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code example as per your own requirements.